# CPQ quote line showing multi-time

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter

I am working on salesforce CPQ quote while I am adding the product under quote line its showing multi-time like Add product button Add group button here I enclosed the image help how to solve this even I reinstall and install the salesforce cpq package again it showing twice the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you got this error a few months ago. 
I guess the components are conflicting due to some changes in org & configuration settings.
If you are still facing this issue, you should raise the ticket with Salesforce CPQ.